# AS3 to PHP - mail() function

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, email

When I click on send the textbox displays 'sending....' with no change.
I'm very sure that this was working before, but the client has noticed it not working recently. I can't find the problem, please help.

I have a swf with this AS3

```
var var_load:URLLoader = new URLLoader;  
var URL_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "http://www.blah.com/send_email_auto_response.php" );  
URL_request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;  

function submit(e:MouseEvent):void
{  
    if( contact_name.text == "" || contact_email.text == "" ||
        contact_subject.text == "" || contact_message.text == "" )  
    {  
        message_status.text = "Please fill up all text fields.";  
    }  
    else if( !validate_email(contact_email.text) )  
    {  
        message_status.text = "Please enter the valid email address.";  
    }
    else  
    {  
        message_status.text = "sending...";     
        var email_data:String = "name=" + contact_name.text
                       + "&email=" + contact_email.text
                       + "&subject=" + contact_subject.text
                       + "&message=" + contact_message.text;

        var URL_vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(email_data);
        URL_vars.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

        URL_request.data = URL_vars;
        var_load.load( URL_request );
        var_load.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, receive_response );
    }  
}
```

that calls a page with this PHP code..

```
$contact_name = $_POST['name'];    
$contact_email = $_POST['email'];    
$contact_subject = $_POST['subject'];  
$contact_message = $_POST['message'];  
if( $contact_name == true )  
{  
    $sender = $contact_email;  
    $receiver = "info@blah.com";  
    $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  

    $email_body = "Name: $contact_name \nEmail: $sender \n\nSubject: $contact_subject \n\nMessage: \n\n$contact_message \n\nIP: $client_ip \n\n";  
    $email_body_auto_reply = "Hello $contact_name, \nThis is the auto reply message. Thank you.";  

    $extra = "From: $sender\r\n" . "Reply-To: $sender \r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    $extra_auto_reply = "From: $receiver\r\n" . "Reply-To: $receiver \r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    mail( $sender, "Auto Reply - Re: $contact_subject", $email_body_auto_reply, $extra_auto_reply );    // auto reply mail to sender

    if( mail( $receiver, "Flash Contact Form - $contact_subject", $email_body, $extra ) )
    {
        echo "success=yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "success=no";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the PHP function from an HTML page to narrow it down?

Comment: I just tried hitting the HTML page and it displays a blank page, even after adding extra echo's after the $_POST vars.

Comment: Have you enabled display_errors in your PHP configuration? Try adding this as the first line of your PHP script: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');`

Comment: @shanethehat after adding that, when hitting...

http://www.blah.com/send_email_auto_response.php?name=blah&email=blah@hotmail.com&subject=test2&message=test_message_2

I get...
Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/blahblah/public_html/send_email_auto_response.php on line 5 to 8

these are 
`code` $contact_name = $_POST['name'];
$contact_email = $_POST['email'];
$contact_subject = $_POST['subject'];
$contact_message = $_POST['message'];

Comment: So your variables are either not being sent, or are not arriving in the expected format.  Try dumping the content of the $_POST array before your other code:  `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_POST); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: @shanethehat that gives - array(0) { }

Comment: This link you provided in your previous comment is passing the variables using GET instead of POST, this isn't going to work. Use the Flash form for testing, and use the net panel of Firebug to inspect the response from your PHP script. Then you should see the contents of the POST array, and any errors that are occurring.

Comment: ahh yes good point. I don't have access to the current fla but the swf on the web at the moment displays as Form Data

subject:test2
name:matt
email:matt@hotmail.com
message:test 2 mesage
dataFormat:text

This is Chrome Network Debug

Comment: I have this problem when I use special characters, like `&`. Maybe that could be it?

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly need:

```
URL_vars.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
```

changing to:

```
URL_vars.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
```

Comment: I don't have access to the up to date .fla at the moment, I'll have to try this later depending the above discussion not resolving the problem. Thanks